# Laravel equivalent of ->fetch?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a website that uses PHP and SQL to connect to the database, I'm trying to replace all the SQL with Laravel Query Builder commands.

I am running into a problem with the following code:

```
public function queryUsers()
{
    $db = $this->getMysql();
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $this->addedUsers[$row['user_id']] = $row["slack_handle"];
        $this->addedUserNames[$row['user_id']] = $row["name"];
    }
}
```

I can easily connect to the database using Laravel, however I am not sure how to continue after the code shown below:

```
public function queryUsers()
{
    $stmt = DB::table('users')->get();
}
```

TLDR:
In PHP/PDO **Fetch** fetches the next row from a result set, I'm curious if Laravel has an easy way to do the same.

Comment: `->get()` does that. Try to `dd($stmt);` after that line and see what it contains.

Comment: What have you tried to go further? There should be tons of tutorials about this topic

Comment: chunk is a nice eloquent replacement for fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function queryUsers()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    // $users is array of Std Object. 
    foreach($users as $key => $user) {
        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
        // $user->name, $user->address
    }      
}
```

Comment: please, add more description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
foreach($users as $user){ ... }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries